# Assigning to an optional variable in swift 3.0 using ? operator returns nil

Tags: swift, option-type

Consider the following code.

```
var a:Int?

a? = 10

print(a)
```

Here the variable a isn't getting assigned the value 10. If it is because of the '?' operator, why compiler doesn't show a compilation error?.

Comment: Generally don't use exclamation and question marks at variables on the left side of an assignment.

Comment: @Bibin P Sebastian Still, have you any confusion about optional (?) in swift?

Comment: @Bibin P Sebastian You are technically assigning value to optionally unwrapped variable. So a? evaluates to nil and you are trying to assign to nil(i.e  nil = 10). Does it make sense. And its a valid statement as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221293/optional-chaining-used-in-left-side-of-assignment-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var a:Int?

a = 10

print(a)
```

Well...

> **? (Optional)** indicates your variable may contain a nil value while **! (unwrapper)** indicates your variable must have a memory (or value) when it is used (tried to get a value from it) at runtime.

The main difference is that optional chaining fails gracefully when the optional is nil, whereas forced unwrapping triggers a runtime error when the optional is `nil`.

```
var defaultNil : Int?  // declared variable with default nil value
println(defaultNil) >> nil  

var canBeNil : Int? = 4
println(canBeNil) >> optional(4)

canBeNil = nil
println(canBeNil) >> nil

println(canBeNil!) >> // Here nil optional variable is being unwrapped using ! mark (symbol), that will show runtime error. Because a nil optional is being tried to get value using unwrapper

var canNotBeNil : Int! = 4
print(canNotBeNil) >> 4

var cantBeNil : Int = 4
cantBeNil = nil // can't do this as it's not optional and show a compile time error
```

[Here is basic tutorial in detail, by Apple Developer Committee.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)