# how to unwrap swift optionals within a struct

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm learning swift and found an example that contains an optional property within a struct. When I try to set a value to the optional I find that it is nil.

```
struct Price{
    var USD: Double = 0.0
    var CAD: Double = 0.0
}
struct Item{
    var name: String = "not defined"
    var price: Price?
}


var purchase:Item = Item()
purchase.name = "lampshade"
purchase.price?.USD = 19.2


print("purchase name is \(purchase.name), purchase price is \(purchase.price?.USD)")
```

yields

```
purchase name is lampshade, purchase price is nil
```

if I try (purchase.price.USD) I get an error "Value of optional type 'Price?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'USD' of wrapped base type 'Price'

How can I unwrap price in order to set a value of USD?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/29221293/1187415: `purchase.price` has no value, so that the “optional chaining assignment” simply does nothing.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Assigning to an optional variable in swift 3.0 using ? operator returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43999142/1187415).

Comment: You can think of initializing the price `var price: Price = Price()`  in `Item`model, instead of making it optional

Comment: Martin R Thank you that did not come up in my initial search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly set a property of an `Optional` if you haven't assigned a value to the `Optional` itself, since due to the optional chaining, the setter of `usd` won't be called.

Instead, you need to assign a `Price` to `purchase.price`.

```
var purchase:Item = Item()
purchase.name = "lampshade"
purchase.price = Price(USD: 19.2)
```

Or if you want to assign an "empty" `price`, then optional chaining on that works, since now `price` is not `nil`.

```
var purchase:Item = Item()
purchase.name = "lampshade"
purchase.price = Price()
purchase.price?.USD = 19.2
```

Also, you should try to make properties immutable immutable (`let`) by default and only make properties mutable (`var`) if they really need to change after initialisation. You should also only add default values to properties where it makes sense for them to have a default value. For instance, `name` shouldn't have one, but rather, should be immutable with its value being set in the `init`.

```
struct Item{
    let name: String
    var price: Price?
}


var purchase = Item(name: "lampshade")
purchase.price = Price(USD: 19.2)
```

Comment: To complete the print I needed to also code the following to unwrap  --- print("purchase name is \(purchase.name), purchase price is \(purchase.price!.USD)")